# How to combine two variables i.e. date and time in Angular

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework

I have one doubt that is regarding combining date and time which is stored in two different variables. I am using Angular and Django REST and Datefield data, timefield data is fetched from the Django REST API which is stored in two variables in Angular side, is it possible to combine two fields?

model

```
 class Clinics(models.Model):
        id = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='clint')
        staff= models.ForeignKey(Staff, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='staff')
        assessment = models.ForeignKey(Assesment, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
        date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
        time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can extract all the elements of your date and time you can do

```
new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond, etc)
```

Which will create a new angular date